# PostgreSQL query for intervals of 1 min with accumulated sum over all the timeframe

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by

I'm struggling with this query so far i can create the intervals of 1 min but the sum of the two columns that I need is given for just that min and not the accumulated sum over time

```
SELECT
    TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' +
    INTERVAL '1 second' * round(extract('epoch' from "Timestamp") / 60) * 60 as Timestamp",
    SUM("Particles"), sum("Bio")
from "Results" 
where "SampleID" = 50 
GROUP BY round(extract('epoch' from "Timestamp") / 60)
ORDER BY "Timestamp" DESC
```

that is the query that i'm using and the results are these

```
          Timestamp      |Sum |Sum
"2013-08-09 14:17:00-07" | 61 | 4
"2013-08-09 14:16:00-07" | 64 | 6
"2013-08-09 14:15:00-07" | 29 | 5
"2013-08-09 14:14:00-07" | 96 | 1
"2013-08-09 14:13:00-07" | 43 | 2
```

but i need the accumulative sum of those last two colums

```
Select
    TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' +
    INTERVAL '1 second' * round(extract('epoch' from "Timestamp") / 60) * 60 as "Timestamp",
    sum("Particles") over (order by "Timestamp") as Cumulative_Part, 
    sum("Bio") over (order by "Timestamp") as Cumulative_Bio from "Results" 
where
    "SampleID" = 50 and
    "Timestamp" between '2013-08-09 14:13:00' and '2013-08-09 14:17:00'
GROUP BY round(extract('epoch' from "Timestamp") / 60)
Order by "Timestamp" DESC
```

Comment: Yeah it work i just had to change it a little bit thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have postgresql 8.4  or above, you can use a `OVER(ORDER BY..)` construct

```
SELECT...
, SUM("Particles") OVER(ORDER BY TimeStamp_Field) as SUM_Particles
...
```

see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) for more info

Comment: I get an error saying "column "Results.Particles" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: Please add the new full SQL statement to your orignal question. It's hard to tell what is going on just from your comment.

Comment: I know that the problem is something to do with the way i get the interval, because i try your answer without getting the interval and works fine but i need to separate the timestamp in 1 min intervals